# Do you feel comfortable with integral u-substitution? (reverse chain rule)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I've made this post both to see if I'm thinking right and to let others read and understand where the "u-substitution" method for integration comes from. I really hate substitutions, because you lost track of what's happening. I've read the related posts in this forum and concluded the following:

The integral u-substitution is a nice method to find some integrals. It comes from the chain rule:

$$\frac{df(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$$

For me, $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is just a notation for the derivative of the function $f$ with respect to $x$, so there's no mean for just $df$ or just $dx$ alone.

When we integrate both sides:

$$\int \frac{df(g(x))}{dx}dx = \int\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\frac{dg(x)}{dx}dx$$

Then:
$$\underbrace{f(g(x)) + C}_{\text{integral of a derivative}}= \int\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\frac{dg(x)}{dx}dx\tag{1}$$

So if we want to integrate some function in the form $\int\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\frac{dg(x)}{dx}dx$ this is gonna be equal $f(g(x)) + C$. That's why we can integrate $\cos(2x)$ this way:

$$\int \cos(2x)dx = \int \frac{d\sin(2x)}{d2x}\frac{2}{2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d\sin(2x)}{d2x}\cdot2 \ \ dx$$

See how I didn't change the integrand at all, but I multiplied and divided by $2$ to get the form $$\frac{d\sin(2x)}{d[2x]}\frac{d[2x]}{dx} = \frac{d\cos(2x)}{dx}$$ 
Then, I can match the pattern in $(1)$ to integrate like this:
$$\begin{align}  &\int\frac{d\color{#F01C2C}{f(}\color{Blue}{g(x)}\color{#F01C2C}{)}}{d\color{Blue}{g(x)}}\color{#01cf84}{\frac{dg(x)}{dx}}dx = \color{#F01C2C}{f(}\color{Blue}{g(x)}\color{#F01C2C}{)} + C \\
\int \cos(2x)dx = \frac{1}{2}&\int\frac{d\color{#F01C2C}{\sin(\color{Blue}{2x})}}{d\color{Blue}{2x}}\cdot\color{#01cf84}{\ \ 2} \ \ \ \ dx = \frac{1}{2}\color{#F01C2C}{\sin(\color{Blue}{2x})} + C\end{align}$$

So... am I right? Do you feel comfortable doing substitutions? Would this technique be acceptable in my math tests? (I really prefer this than the substitution method).

**Update**:

Let's do this integral: 
$$\int x\ln(\cos(x^2))\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx$$
I will derivate $\cos(x^2)$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\cos(x^2) = -2x\sin(x^2)$$

Then I'll multiply and divide the integrand by this result:

$$
\begin{align}
\int x\ln(\cos(x^2))\sin(x^2) \color{#F01C2C}{\frac{-2x\sin(x^2)}{-2x\sin(x^2)}}dx = \color{#F01C2C}{-\frac{1}{2}}&\int \ln(\cos(x^2))\cdot\color{#F01C2C}{-2x\sin(x^2)}dx
\\ &\int\frac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)} \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{dg(x)}{dx} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ dx
\\=&f(g(x)) + C
\end{align}
$$
So to integrate this, we just have to find the antiderivative of $\ln$ and apply it to the 'point' $\cos(x^2)$. The antiderivative of $\ln$ is $x(\ln(x) - 1)$ by integration by parts. Applying it to $\cos(x^2)$ we have: $\cos(x^2)(\ln(\cos(x^2))-1)$ (this is the antiderivative at $\cos(x^2)$ or $g(x)$. Back in our integral:

$$\color{#F01C2C}{-\frac{1}{2}}\int \ln(\cos(x^2))\cdot\color{#F01C2C}{-2x\sin(x^2)}dx = \color{#F01C2C}{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos(x^2)(\ln(\cos(x^2))-1)$$

Comment: Way too much syntactic noise for me. I can't see why this method would be superior to the standard substitution method. Besides, you showed only trivial examples where you can easily guess the solution, even without any substitutions. What about more complicated ones? In my opinion, clarity will suffer a lot.

Comment: Just something to think about:  How would you apply that method to an integral such as $$\int x\ln(\cos(x^2))\sin(x^2)\mathrm dx?$$

Comment: (1) You say you dislike substitution because "you lost track of what's happening".  What do you mean?  I've never felt that I lost track of anything because of substitution.  (2) You ask whether your technique would be acceptable in your tests.  We don't know; ask whoever will grade your tests.

Comment: @jnh I updated my answer, check the integral :)

Comment: @StevenTaschuk I mean that's an abstraction. You do it mechanically. At least, for me, it's harder to see that u-substitution is the reverse of chain rule, while in my method, it's clear.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, I think this is normal when you polish a method for practical use.  Compare integration by parts: the usual formula obscures the connection to the product rule, but is well-adapted to the practical situation where you have one integral and want to change it into a more tractable one.  Of course it's good to be familiar with the origin of a technique, but that's usually just a distraction when you're actually computing.

Comment: @LucasZanella That is the correct answer.  But you could have done it like this.  Let $u=\cos(x^2),$ then $du=-2x\sin(x^2)\ dx.$ Then we have $-\frac12\int\ln(u)\mathrm du.$ Since you know how to find the antiderivative of $-\frac12\ln u$, then you know it will be $-\frac{u}{2}(\ln u-1).$  Now just plug substitute it back. This just seems shorter than your method.  But, you do have the correct answer.

Comment: @jnh yep, integration by u-substitution is a lot faster, I admit!

Comment: I'm doing all this because I'm thinking in how a computer could integrate by some algorithm, and it seems that if I understand the reverse chain rule, I can make a better algorithm. Also, how do you guys determine the right function to substitute for $u$? I only know wich one to do, because I always try to find the derivative of the inside function, in the integrand.

Comment: @LucasZanella Verifying that the integrand has two factors, one of which is the derivative of the inside of the other (up to scaling), is exactly how you determine the right function to substitute.

Comment: (Also, +1 --- this is a well-asked problem with clear evidence of thought and prior work!)

Comment: @Neal thanks! I like to think and then ask, nobody's here to do the other's homework. The technique you mentioned is exactly how I think in my method. Thanks again :)

Comment: I tend to think that an easier way to write it is as follows: Abusing notation slightly, consider the functions $u$ and $v$. By the product rule for derivatives, $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$. Integrating both sides gives the desired result.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman wich result? Shouldn't it be chain rule? $uov = u'ov\cdot v'$?

Comment: There are useful substitutions other than those coming from "oh, hey, this piece of the integrand is the derivative of that piece".  One well-known example is the [tangent half-angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Comment: @StevenTaschuk thank's, I'm gonna build a method inside this topic too c:

Comment: @LucasZanella The "chain rule" is used for the composition of functions; finding the derivative of the product of functions (i.e., after multiplying two functions together) is generally found with what is known as the "product rule."

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I know, but the u-substitution uses the reverse of chain rule, I didn't understand why you said about product rule.

Comment: You really did use my color! Nice!

Comment: @mixedmath yep (｡◕‿◕｡) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By the comments and the question itself, you seem to be looking for techniques to get integrals (antiderivatives, really) symbolically. There are algorithms for this (see e.g. [symbolic integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_integration)), but they aren't very suitable for hand calculation.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your **question**: Yes, I feel comfortable with the method of "$u$-substitution". I don't feel comfortable with **calling** it "$u$-substitution" because it seems silly to name it after a letter of the alphabet. (I don't like the term "$M$-test" very much either.) I just call it "substitution", so I can use whatever letter I like for the new variable.

To answer **your other question**: If I were teaching calculus, I would consider it quite acceptable for you to use your technique on a test. However, if you were to complain that the test was too long, I might point out that I'd shown you a more efficient procedure for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I always felt that the substitution method is used only to 'simplify the integral', nothing more. Though substitution method makes you lose track of what you were doing, all you need to do is to organize the way you write.

Though your way to solve the integral is quite impressive, I feel that one would lose track during the **start** of the race by following your method.

Consider an integral 
$$
\int_{}^{} [ \sqrt{cot x} + \sqrt{tan x} ]dx
$$

where you need to substitute twice, which would be a way more problematic integral if you do not use substitution. Its just like pouring fuel to fire.

I am not saying your method sucks, (damn, I never thought of solving it that way! You are too good!) but just that substitution method provides you more flexibility without writing much.